# Python IDLE always crashes on my Mac, how can I fix it?

Tags: python, django, macos, python-idle

I'm using Mac OS 10.9, and when I open Terminal, enter Python IDLE, and input some code like:

```
$ django-admin.py startproject mysite
$ python manage.py runserver
$ python manage.py syncdb
$ from django.db import models
```

Especially input `from django.db import models`, then the Python IDLE will crash. It happens every time. Why is this happening? How can I fix it?

Comment: It is IDLE instead of IDEL

Comment: I don't know IDLE, but it looks like you're trying to run Python code within a terminal shell, not within Python (your last command). You'll need to run that in the Python interpreter instead.

Comment: What @Evert said; the first three commands are terminal commands. The fourth line is meant to be part of a Python module or a entered into a Python shell.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to play with your models from the command line, you'll first need to start a Python shell. As @evert mentioned in his comment, your fourth line cannot simply be typed into a Mac/Linux shell.

You could work with models in a Python shell if you wanted using the manage.py shell:

```
$ python manage.py shell
Python 2.7.3 (default, Aug  1 2012, 05:16:07) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from django.db import models
```